# ogr2ogr from MIF to KML including MID generating split kmls

Tags: kml, ogr2ogr, mif

I have a set of MIF  and MID files that I would like to translate to KML.

I used ogr2ogr to transform the MIF into one big KML which worked ok like so:

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" geo-kml geo-mif
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I incorporate the accompanied MID file into the KML?
2. Can I make seperate KMLS for each placemark in the MIF?

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo MID and MIF belong together and GDAL does use them both when it does the conversion. I suppose that you think that MIF is not used because you do not see all the attributes in the resulting KML. That is probably due to differences in the formats and limitations in the GDAL KML driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html.
If you can share a sample of your data (geo-mif) we can see what we can do with it.